# Wordpress: Forminator form select field value not displaying properly on tablesome table

Tags: wordpress

I have a form that includes multiple fields, but I encounter an issue when displaying selected input fields and radio buttons such as 'Country' and 'Status of Availability' in a Tablesome table. When I select 'Afghanistan', it appears correctly in Forminator submissions. However, when attempting to display all the data in table format using the Tablesome plugin, the country field displays 'one' or 'two' instead of 'Afghanistan'. Similarly, when selecting 'yes' from the radio button on the 'Status of Availability' field, it displays 'one' instead of 'yes'. The rest of the fields display correctly.
Forminator Form:
[image]
after submitted tablesome table. where i need the selected value but it displays one or two:
[image]

Comment: This site is for questions about programming